# Refactor to remove Taks.Run from my code

Tags: c#, async-await

I just wrote the following code

```
public void Save()
{
   while (this.IsAsyncInProcess)
       Thread.Sleep(100);

   this.customer.OrderCount = this.orders.Count();
   this.customer.OrderTotal =  this.orders.Sum(o => x.Total);
   this.customerRepo.Save();
}

public async Task LoadAsync()
{
    this.IsAsyncInProcess = true;
    this.customer = await this.customerRepo.GetCustomerAsync(...);
    this.orders = await this.customerRepo.GetOrdersAsync(...);
    this.IsAsyncInProcess = false;
}
```

Now I had a classical deadlock because, after `this.orders` completed, it would wait for the gui thread to resume in order to set `this.IsAsyncInProcess` to `false`. However, the gui thread was busy inside `Save()`

Now I refactored `LoadAsync` to

```
public async Task LoadAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        this.IsAsyncInProcess = true;
        this.customer = await this.customerRepo.GetCustomerAsync(...);
        this.orders = await this.customerRepo.GetOrdersAsync(...);
        this.IsAsyncInProcess = false;
    });
}
```

I can't just refactor `Save` to `SaveAsync` for compability reasons.

Is there a better way to achive this, without using `Task.Run`?

Comment: Instead of spin-wait, have you tried using a [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) or AutoResetEvent?

Comment: Twiddling a boolean is *not* a reliable way to do synchronization. At the very least memory barriers are required.

Comment: Have you considered storing that `Task` returned by `LoadAsync` in a shared property, rather than this boolean flag? Then instead of spinning/waiting for the flag to become unset, you could just queue a continuation on that task using `ContinueWith` (Or then just make `Save` async and await it)

Comment: There would also be the possibilities of using ReadWriteLock amongst other synchronization techniques ... Maybe this is also for you: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncReaderWriterLock

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how `Save` and `LoadAsync` are related? Why does `Save` need to wait for `LoadAsync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async locking. If you can't change the signiture of Save then you can just proxy to an async local function.

```
static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

public void Save()
{
   SaveAsync();
   public async Task SaveAsync()
   {
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        try{
           this.customer.OrderCount = this.orders.Count();
           this.customer.OrderTotal =  this.orders.Sum(o => x.Total);
           this.customerRepo.Save();
        }finally{
           sem.Release();
        }
    }
}


public async Task LoadAsync()
{
    await sem.WaitAsync();
    try{
        this.customer = await this.customerRepo.GetCustomerAsync(...);
        this.orders = await this.customerRepo.GetOrdersAsync(...);
    }finally{
       sem.Release();
    }
}
```

or even better create your own async lock

```
static SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

public static async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync(){
    await sem.WaitAsync();
    return Disposable.Create(()=>sem.Release());
}

public void Save()
{
   SaveAsync();
   public async Task SaveAsync()
   {
        using(await LockAsync()){
           this.customer.OrderCount = this.orders.Count();
           this.customer.OrderTotal =  this.orders.Sum(o => x.Total);
           this.customerRepo.Save();
        }
    }
}

public async Task LoadAsync()
{
    using(await LockAsync()){
        this.customer = await this.customerRepo.GetCustomerAsync(...);
        this.orders = await this.customerRepo.GetOrdersAsync(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why is the Semaphore is static?

Comment: Not really. It depends on the scope of protection. If multiple instances of the class that has Save and Load are independent then make it non static. If you have other classes or other instances that need to be protected from each other then make it static.